# Multivariable chain rule and the behaviour of derivatives

Tags: multivariable-calculus, partial-derivative, chain-rule

Suppose we have a function f (x , y) where **x** and **y** are functions of **u** and **v** i.e. x (u,v) and y (u,v).

Then, from the chain rule, the following relationship holds $$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} + \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

However, on the RHS of the equation, can the two $\partial x$ and $\partial y$ not cancel like a fraction, which would then give $\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = 2\frac{\partial f}{\partial u}$, which is a contradiction?

**In fact**, when is it that the derivatives can be cancelled out like in a fraction, and when can they not?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: “Canceling” numerators and denominators can useful as a mnemonic, but the bottom line is that there are not fractions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that they don’t cancel because they represent product of derivatives, for instance

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial u} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial u} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial u}$$

$$\frac{\partial f}{\partial v} = \frac{\partial f}{\partial x} \cdot \frac{\partial x}{\partial v} +  \frac{\partial f}{\partial y} \cdot \frac{\partial y}{\partial v}$$

To better understand the concept you should consider that chain rule is just obtained by matrix product of gradient and/or jacobians.

In the example given:

$$\nabla f(u,v)=
\begin{bmatrix}f_u\\f_v\end{bmatrix}=
\begin{bmatrix}x_u&y_u\\x_v&y_v\end{bmatrix}\cdot
\begin{bmatrix}f_x\\f_y\end{bmatrix}$$